# Modify sys.path or $PYTHONPATH so that my app works with a different version of Python and its site-packages

Tags: python, linux, flask, sys, pythonpath

I have a Flask App deployed on a server, which is trying to use the Python3.10 version and its installed site-packages. **I removed this version** for certain reasons and **I want to change the path to the previously installed version** (Python 3.9).

From the Linux terminal, I run the command:

```
python3 -m site --user-site
```

and receive:

`/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`

It's strange because I supposedly removed that version (or maybe not correctly). And when I launch the command:

```
print(sys.path)
```

in the python3 console, I get the following path:

`['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']`

*(If I want to use Python3.10 console I can... because remainds installed...)*

Could it be that I need to add something to the first element of the list? (['', '/usr...])

In the

```
pyvenv.cfg
```

I have:

`home = /usr/local/bin include-system-site-packages = true version = 3.9.2`

And in the

```
bashrc
```

I added:

`export PATH=$PATH:/apps/venv/lib/python3.9 export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.9`

My app cannot run because it's still trying to find libraries from version 3.10, and I need to configure it to search for those of version 3.9...

If I run

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.10,
```

`I always get this: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Note, selecting 'postgresql-plpython3-10' for regex 'python3.10' Package 'postgresql-plpython3-10' is not installed, so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.`

**Any advice or help please?**

Any advice or help please?